# Passing data between viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Im wondering how I can pass a value between viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear if it's conditionally created in ViewDidLoad and not initialized.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    if let foo = self.foo {
        let webView = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
        scrollView.addSubView(webView)
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear() {
    // How do I use my conditionally created webView here?
    func doSomething(webView: UIWebView) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Instance variables.

Comment: [Swift Programming Language: Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID254)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both methods are in the same scope - they are inside the same class instance, you can use an instance variable then, e.g.:

```
fileprivate var webView: UIWebView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let foo = self.foo {
        let webView = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
        scrollView.addSubView(webView)

        self.webView = webView
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()

    if let webView = self.webView {
       // do something with my webView
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any drawbacks to using global vars that might never be used?

Comment: @patrikqvarnstrom By 'global var' do you actually mean property? It's a waste of resources, but Xcode will tell you if a property is never used (it'll also tell you if a `var` should be a `let` because it's never mutated).

Answer (score 1):

Just move `webView` to class scope and you can access it everywhere within your class

```
class MyClass : UIViewController
{

    var webView : UIWebView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if let foo = self.foo {
            webView = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
            scrollView.addSubView(webView)
        }
        else
        {
            webView = nil // or set to some default
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear() {
        // How do I use my conditionally created webView here?
        if webView != nil
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `nil` is the default for optionals. No need to set it again in `else`.

Comment: true - I always try to keep the code very obvious and explicit - so I sometimes overdeclare

Answer (score 1):

You can set you webView as global variable:

```
var webView : UIWebView?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if let foo = self.foo {
            self.webView = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
            scrollView.addSubView(self.webView!)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear() {
        // How do I use my conditionally created webView here?

        func doSomething(webView: UIWebView) {
            // Do stuff
        }

        if let myWebView = self.webView{

            doSomething(webView: myWebView)

        }

    }
```

A better way to di something similar :

```
var webView : UIWebView?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if let foo = self.foo {
            self.webView = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
            scrollView.addSubView(self.webView!)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear() {
        // How do I use my conditionally created webView here?

        if let myWebView = self.webView{

            self.doSomething(webView: myWebView)

        }

    }

    func doSomething(webView: UIWebView) {
        // Do stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
    class ViewController
    {
         //Init glabal variable
         let webView:UIWebView? = nil

          override func viewDidLoad() 
          {
             if let foo = self.foo {
               webView = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
               scrollView.addSubView(webView)
          }

          override func viewDidAppear() 
          {
              if(webView != nil)
              {
                  func doSomething(webView: UIWebView) 
                  {
                     // Do stuff
                   }
              }
         }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use webView as global variable

```
let webView : UIWebview {
    return UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    if let foo = self.foo {
        scrollView.addSubView(webView)
    }
}
override func viewDidAppear() {
    doSomething()
}

func doSomething() {
    // Do stuff
}
```

or you can access to scrollview subviews

```
for subview in scrollView.subviews {
    if subview is UIWebview {
        doSomething(webview: subview as! UIWebView)
    }
}
```